# How can I fetch backend data in child component and then retrieve an object from store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My parent component `<Room/>` build children components `<RoomSensor/>`, when parent build these children I also send to the `<RoomSensor/>` uuid, by this uuid I fetch sensor data from a backend.

Store is array of objects.

```js
// Parent <Room/>

return props.sensors.map((uuid, index) => {
  return <RoomSensor key={index} uuid={uuid}/>
})
```

```js
// Children <RoomSensor/>

const RoomSensor = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")
    props.fetchSensor(props.uuid)
  }, [props.uuid])

  console.log(props.sensor)

  return (
    <div className={"col-auto"}>
      <small><b>{props.sensor.value}</b></small>
    </div>
  )

}


let mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    sensor: filterSensor(state, props.uuid)
  }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchSensor,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoomSensor)
```

```js
// Selectors
export const getSensor = (state, uuid) => {
  return _.filter(state.sensors, ["uuid", uuid])[0]
}


export const filterSensor = createSelector(
  getSensor,
  (sensor) => sensor
)
```

And I cannot understand two things:

1. When I do refresh I get.

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined
```

I understand that there is no data in the state yet, that's why such an error occurs. Is it possible not to render the component until the data comes from the server?

2. If I comment `<small><b>{props.sensor.value}</b></small>` no errors occur, data appears in the store, then I uncomment this line and voila everything works. But in the console I see too many component rerende. What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with the selector?
   [image]

In general, I want each sensor component to render independently of the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is based on a few assumptions derived from the shared code and output:

1. Currently, there's a hard-coded list of 4 sensor UUIDs.
2. `createSelector` is from the `reselect` package.
3. `_` references an import of the `lodash` package.

---

**"Is it possible not to render the component until the data comes from the server?"**

The short answer to this is yes. There're several approaches to achieve this, so you'll want to evaluate what fits best with the structure of the app. Here're 2 approaches for consideration:

1. Retrieve the list of sensors from the server. Initialize the store with an empty list and populate it upon getting data back from the server.
2. In `getSensor`, return a default value if the uuid isn't in the list.

Either way, I'd recommend adding default state to the store. This will help reduce the amount of code required to handle edge cases.

Here's a rough example of what the new reducer and selector for (1) might look like:

```
export const storeReducer = (state, action) => {
  let nextState = state;
  if (!state) {
    // State is uninitialized, so give it a default value
    nextState = {
      sensors: [],
    };
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECEIVE_SENSORS':
      // We received sensor data, so update the value in the store
      nextState = {
        ...nextState,
        sensors: action.sensors,
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return nextState;
};

export const getSensors(state) {
  return state.sensors;
}
```

The action upon receiving the data from the server, could look something like:

```
dispatch({
  sensors,
  type: 'RECEIVE_SENSORS',
})
```

---

**"...in the console I see too many component rerende[rs]"**

Without additional context, it's hard to say *exactly* why the re-renders are happening, but the most likely cause is that each call to `props.fetchSensor(props.uuid)` changes the data in the store (e.g. if it's overwriting the data).

From the console output you shared, we see that there're 16 re-renders, which would happen because:

1. Each of the 4 instances of `RoomSensor` calls `fetchSensor`
2. This results in 4 updates to the store's state
3. Each update to the store's state causes React to evaluate each instance of `RoomSensor` for re-render
4. Hence, 4 state updates x 4 components evaluated = 16 re-renders

React is pretty efficient and if your component returns the same value as the previous run, it knows not to update the DOM. So, the performance impact probably isn't actually that significant.

That said, if the above theory is correct and you want to reduce the number of re-renders, one way to do it would be to check whether the data you get back from the server is the same as what's already in the store and, if so, skip updating the store.

For example, `fetchSensor` might be updated with something like:

```
const existingData = getSensor(getState(), uuid);
const newData = fetch(...);
// Only update the store if there's new data or there's a change
if (!existingData || !_.isEqual(newData, existingData)) {
  dispatch(...);
}
```

This would require updating `getSensor` to return a falsey value (e.g. `null`) if the uuid isn't found in the list of sensors.

---

**One additional tip**

In `Room`, `RoomSensor` is rendered with its `key` based on the item's index in the array. Since `uuid` should be unique, you can use that as the `key` instead (i.e. `<RoomSensor key={uuid} uuid={uuid} />`). This would allow React to base updates to `RoomSensor` on just the uuid instead of also considering the order of the list.

---